# Flutter AssetEntity Name vs Asset Name

Tags: flutter

I'm using multi image picker package and photo manager. The first one for select photo and the second one for see all the photo.
I'm searching for get the image name and the result is the two package method return two different name.
For example in multi image picker there is :

```
 ** MULTI IMAGE PICKER **
 asset.name
```

for take the name of the image.

And with photo manager i use

```
** PHOTO MANAGER **
_getNames(List<AssetEntity> immaginiMostrate) async {
List<String> fileNames = [];
for (int i = 0; i < immaginiMostrate.length; i++) {
  final imageName = await immaginiMostrate[i].titleAsync;
  fileNames.add(imageName);
}
```

And this return two different string result.
Is there a method for get the same image name for both method or maybe for convert AssetEntity to asset or in reverse?

Edit:

For example the first command asset.name return :'3b8067fe-2a0c-4fa6-bb0d-d33ab824eb65.jpg" and the second 'IMG_0360.JPG'

Or maybe can be a method to convert this 3b8067fe-2a0c-4fa6-bb0d-d33ab824eb65.jpg to this 'IMG_0360.JPG'

Answer (score 0):

For now the only answer i can take to my self is to use id.

```
**PHOTO MANAGER**
immaginiMostrate[i].id;


**MULTI MULTI IMAGE PICKER**
asset.identifier;
```

This is the only parameters that are equals in both package.
So if you have to confront value turned from both package like me this is the only way to do that.